# Reading numerical data with csv reader

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to read a csv table with csv reader, I want to rewrite the data into a tuple of tuples, where every subtuple contains the data of one row in the original file.
I am doing the following and it is working fine, but you can see how ugly it looks.

```
table1 = tuple()
with open('data.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
        table1 = table1.__add__(tuple([tuple([float(row[0]), float(row[1])])]))  # giving that I know the data is arranged in two columns
print(table1)
```

The output looks good:

```
((0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0), (0.00543154732031037, 4.2724591391866636e-05), (0.0347155846128363, 0.00021518683772895567), (0.1014894975795... etc
```

I am sure there is a better way to do this.
Please note that I can only use the builtin modules, this is why I didn't use Pandas.
Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. What exactly do you want the output to look like? You could e.g. use the `json` module, which would let you render it as nicely formatted JSON.

Comment: @larsks Hi, I am happy with the output as it already looks like, but I believe the last line is written in a quite bad way. I am wondering if there is a better way of reaching the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use a list of tuples - then you could use a list comprehension:

```
with open('data.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    table1 = [(float(row[0]), float(row[1])) for row in reader]
```

If you really need a tuple instead of a list: `tuple()` accepts iterables, so you can pass the list comprehension to it:

```
    table1 = tuple((float(row[0]), float(row[1])) for row in reader)
```

A list/tuple is suitable where you need repeated access/random access to all contained elements.

---

An alternative would be a generator - suitable for all cases where you process the input in a "one-time-only, forward-only" fashion:

```
def read_data(filename):
    with open(filename, newline='') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            yield (float(row[0]), float(row[1]))


for item in read_data('data.csv'):
    print(item)
```

Of course you could create a list from the generator as well:

```
table1 = [item for item in read_data('data.csv')]

# or

table1 = tuple(item for item in read_data('data.csv'))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I guess the second one would work quite well, but the first one would only return one row at a time, meaning that I won't be able to get the whole table as output.

Comment: @Aziz No, the first one returns all rows.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. but still I need them in the form of a tuple. I guess it is now possible to convert it somehow.

Comment: I guess I would just add tuple(table1) in the end.

Comment: @Aziz `table1 = tuple((float(row[0]), float(row[1])) for row in reader)` would also work - I just suspected you might not really need the outer tuple.